# RecyclerView OnItemClick returns IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have implemented an onclick listener in my Recyclerview i however keep getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException, when i click the first item everything works however anything after the first i get the error

when i click the second item i get this error

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
```

The second one this

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 1
```

etc etc

My adapter looks like this

```
class VendorAdapter(private val vendorModel: List<Vendor>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<VendorAdapter.VendorView>() {

    private lateinit var listener: OnItemClickListener

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): VendorView {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_vendor, parent, false)
        return VendorView(view, vendorModel, listener)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: VendorView, position: Int) {

        val vendor = vendorModel[position]

       holder.vendorName.text = vendor.name


        Picasso.get()
                .load(vendorModel[position].img_url)
                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.vendorImage)

        holder.vendor = listOf(vendor)

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return vendorModel.size
    }

    class VendorView(itemView: View, var vendor: List<Vendor>, listener: OnItemClickListener) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {



        val vendorImage: ImageView = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.vendor_image) as ImageView
        val vendorName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.vendor_name)


        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                val position: Int = adapterPosition
                listener.onItemClick(vendor[position])
            }
        }
    }

    interface OnItemClickListener{
        fun onItemClick(vendor: Vendor)
    }

    fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: OnItemClickListener){
        this.listener = listener
    }

}
```

And this is how i call it in my fragment

```
vendorAdapter?.setOnItemClickListener(object : OnItemClickListener {
            override fun onItemClick(vendor: Vendor) {
                Log.e(TAG,"Clicked")
            }

        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your holder.vendor have only one item in it.

```
holder.vendor = listOf(vendor)
```

this will assign a vendor a list with only one item in it.

as a solution with minimal changes, you can change

```
listener.onItemClick(vendor[position])
```

to

```
listener.onItemClick(vendor[0])
```

But holding an array with only one item in it is not a very good practice for me.
Will be better to replace

```
class VendorView(itemView: View, var vendor: List<Vendor>, listener: OnItemClickListener) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
```

to

```
class VendorView(itemView: View, var vendor: Vendor, listener: OnItemClickListener) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
```

and replace

```
listener.onItemClick(vendor[position])
```

to

```
listener.onItemClick(vendor)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `layoutPosition` instead of `adapterPosition`

```
 itemView.setOnClickListener {
                val position: Int = layoutPosition //adapterPosition
                listener.onItemClick(vendor[position])
            }
```

[adapterPosition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getLayoutPosition())

> Returns the Adapter position of the item represented by this
>   ViewHolder.
>
> Note that this might be different than the getLayoutPosition() if
>   there are pending adapter updates but a new layout pass has not
>   happened yet.
>
> **RecyclerView does not handle any adapter updates until the next layout
>   traversal. This may create temporary inconsistencies between what user
>   sees on the screen and what adapter contents have.**

[layoutPosition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getLayoutPosition())

> Returns the position of the ViewHolder in terms of the latest layout
>   pass.